# Troubleshooting Stack Overflow error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a program that performs a calculation in VBA where it references a cells value for multiple rows in the program, and places that value in a another row in the table. Currently, it is finding the correct cell value; however, when it is time to perform the calculation it is giving me a stack overflow error.  I've been trying to fix this but I am not sure what else to do because I have defined all variables properly.

```
Sub Calculate()
    Dim row As Integer 
    Dim frm As Worksheet
    Dim database As Worksheet
     
    Set frm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Installation Grid Test Form")    
    Set database = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Installation Grid Test Database")   

'Calcualtion 10 PSI 1st Step K Value'
 
    With database                 
         For row = Int(2) To Int(1000)           
                If Cells(row, 3).Value = 610 Then
                      .Cells(row, 11).Value = ((Cells(row, 10).Value / 3600) / 386) / (0.525 * ((0.5 / 25.4) ^ 2) * ((60.81) ^ 0.5) * (Cells(row, 9).Value) ^ 0.5)  
                   ElseIf Cells(row, 3).Value = 620 Then                   
                        .Cells(row, 11).Value = ((Cells(row, 10).Value / 3600) / 84) / (0.525 * ((0.5 / 25.4) ^ 2) * ((60.81) ^ 0.5) * (Cells(row, 9).Value) ^ 0.5)
                   ElseIf Cells(row, 3).Value = 630 Then                   
                        .Cells(row, 11).Value = ((Cells(row, 10).Value / 3600) / 70) / (0.525 * ((0.5 / 25.4) ^ 2) * ((60.81) ^ 0.5) * (Cells(row, 9).Value) ^ 0.5)
                   ElseIf Cells(row, 3).Value = 910 Then                    
                       .Cells(row, 11).Value = ((Cells(row, 10).Value / 3600) / 312) / (0.525 * ((0.5 / 25.4) ^ 2) * ((60.81) ^ 0.5) * (Cells(row, 9).Value) ^ 0.5)
                   ElseIf Cells(row, 3).Value = 920 Then
                        .Cells(row, 11).Value = ((Cells(row, 10).Value / 3600) / 84) / (0.525 * ((0.5 / 25.4) ^ 2) * ((60.81) ^ 0.5) * (Cells(row, 9).Value) ^ 0.5)
                   ElseIf Cells(row, 3) = 930 Then                   
                       .Cells(row, 11).Value = ((Cells(row, 10).Value / 3600) / 70) / (0.525 * ((0.5 / 25.4) ^ 2) * ((60.81) ^ 0.5) * (Cells(row, 9).Value) ^ 0.5)
               End If
            Next row
    End With
           
End Sub
```

Comment: All the `Cells` should be have a dot at the front if they refer to the database sheet ie `.Cells`

Comment: Consider dimming row as `Long`

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: How is this sub called?  Does the sheet have any event handlers?

Comment: I can reproduce the error when `Cells(row, 10)` and `Cells(row, 9)` are both blank. Seems to suggest that @CDP1802's advice is correct and you are pointing to the wrong sheet, or you may need to introduce more tests to check whether the cells are blank before performing the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Check that a value in Column I is not blank otherwise dividing by zero will produce overflow error.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Calculate()
    
    Dim frm As Worksheet, database As Worksheet  
    Set frm = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Installation Grid Test Form")
    Set database = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Installation Grid Test Database")

    'Calculation 10 PSI 1st Step K Value'
    Dim r As Long, colC As Long
    Dim c As Double, i As Double, j As Double
    
    Const X as Double = 0.525 * ((0.5 / 25.4) ^ 2) * (60.81 ^ 0.5)
    With database
        For r = 2 To 1000
            colC = .Cells(r, "C")
            Select Case colC
                Case 610: c = 386
                Case 620, 920: c = 84
                Case 630, 930: c = 70
                Case 910: c = 312
                Case Else
                c = 0
            End Select
                ' calc
            If c <> 0 Then
                i = .Cells(r, "I").Value ^ 0.5
                If i <> 0 Then
                    j = .Cells(r, "J").Value / 3600
                    'Debug.Print r, colC, c, i, j, X
                    .Cells(r, "K").Value = j / (c * X * i)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
           
End Sub
```